# Artillery.io - POST binary data

Tags: binary, load, load-testing, binary-data, artillery

How would you send a POST request via artillery with binary data? More specifically I'm trying to do a batch request and have artillery read from the file for the body

I did see in the docs I need to use a custom JS function, but can't seem to get it to correctly pass back the values to artillery:

https://artillery.io/docs/http-reference/#advanced-writing-custom-logic-in-javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i read the post that custom js can be written as followed:

```
'use strict';
 module.exports = {
  generateRandomPayload
};
var contents = require('fs').readFileSync("/home/ec2-user/image_data/data6.json");

function generateRandomPayload(userContext, events, done) {
  var payload = {
    "data":"data"
  };
payload = JSON.parse(contents);
userContext.vars.payload = payload;
return done();
}
```

the artillery yaml file can be like so:

```
config:
target: "https://0giahrna63.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
processor: "./image-payload.js"
phases:
   - duration: 120
   - arrivalRate: 1
scenarios:
   - flow:
   - function: "generateRandomPayload"
   - post:
      url: "/resource"
      json: "{{payload}}"
```

Comment: Though your answer is good, a link to the "post" you refer would have been helpful here

Comment: Check this post : https://artillery.io/blog/using-fakerjs-with-artillery for reference.

Comment: Can we pass parameters inside the function  ex:  "generateRandomPayload(1)"